# append() with ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, append

I'm having problems with `append()` in ie. I checked most solutions but they did not work.
IE is giving me the jQuery error at `qObject.append(createSurveyXmlAnswer(aID));`

Why does this happen and are there any solutions?

```
function createSurveyXmlAnswer(aID){
    var xmlString =  "<answer id = '" + aID + "'>";
    return xmlString;
}
function getAnswer(){
    var aID;
    var qID = parseInt($(document.getElementById("screenView").childNodes[0]).attr("id"));  
    var qType = ($(document.getElementById("screenView").childNodes[0]).attr("class"));  
    var qObject = $("<question id = "+qID+">");
    if(qType.toLowerCase() == "singleselect"){
        aID = singleSelectedSelection(qID);
        qObject.append(createSurveyXmlAnswer(aID));
        setAnswer(aID, qID, qObject);
    }
```

**edit:**

I'm using this to build a jQuery object > xml doc. qID, qType are form attributes, aID is the input value.  The form was created on the fly.

Comment: why are you using `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `$(selector)` when you're using jquery?  seems messy!

Comment: Don't remember, must be having problems using jquery at first so it became a temporary solution. : )

Comment: What are "most solutions" and in what way did they "not work"?

Comment: Trying creating the answer objects with double quotes (i.e. creating the string `<answer id = "aID">` use `xmlString = '<answer id = "' + aID + '">';`

Comment: And _what_ is "the jQuery error"? Can you present a reproducible testcase so that we can debug? We know none of your inputs.

Comment: By the way, this couldn't wouldn't work anyway. You're creating a new object in the line `var qObject = $("<question id = "+qID+">");`, then adding stuff to it, but never using it. I think you meant `var qObject = $('#'+qID);`. Also, for older versions of IE to work properly you probably shouldn't use undefined HTML tags like `<question>` and `<answer>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used javascript xml dom instead of jQuery, more coding but it works on IE.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't parse XML; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Straight from the docs:

> A string of HTML to create on the fly. Note that this parses HTML, **not** XML.

Comment: I'm using a parser to parse the xml, this code is use to build the jquery object that would be parsed later.  That code works as well as with this one on ff, chrome, opera, safari.. just not with ie.

Comment: @Wenn: So some browsers let you get away with it. That doesn't help you with IE, and it doesn't make the code any less incorrect.

Comment: @Wenn `$()` expects an **HTML** string. It doesn't guarantee any correct behavior at all if you put anything other than HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen

`question` and `answer` are not HTML tags.

> are there any solutions?

Use HTML tags instead.